# How to map a nested Collection in Hibernate projection

Tags: java, hibernate

There are two entities:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @ToString.Exclude
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Collection<Address> addresses;

  ...
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "address")
public class Address {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private WebTutorUser user;

  ...
}
```

it is needed to create a projection like this to return a list of objects with each one has users username and a list of addresses:

```
public interface UserProjection {

  String getUsername();

  List<Address> getAddresses();

}
```

and call it in a repository

```
  List<UserProjection> findBy();
```

but it doesn't return addresses list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to create a nested projection:

```
public interface UserProjection {

  String getUsername();

  List<AddressProjection> getAddresses();

  interface AddressProjection {
      String getAddress();
  }

}
```

and it is possible to call it in a repository like that:

```
  List<UserProjection> findBy();
```

or

```
  @Query("select u.username from user u left join fetch u.addresses")
  List<UserProjection> findBy();
```